# Wcf proxy generation on windows mobile application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-mobile, compact-framework

For my mobile app, I used the Add Web References to generate the client proxy to interact with my WCF service.

Then I read somewhere there is an equivalent of SvcUtil for compact framework: NetCFSvcUtil.

Should I be using the NetCFSvcUtil instead of going throught the Add Web References? Or the Add Web References uses NetCFSvcUtil in the background?

Any pros/cons of one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add web reference should be old proxy based on ASMX web services whereas NetCFSvcUtil is tool to generate WCF based proxy. For basic web services there is generally no difference - both will work but if you want to use some advanced WCF features available on CF you will have to use NetCFSvcUtil.