# How to make an Asynchronus call to WCF service from a smart device application?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am developing a smart device application, which is going to communicate with a wcf service over wi-fi. As there is no option to add a service reference into a smart device project I decided to use the NetCFSvcUtil.exe. Everything works great!

But...

In the end I understood that the application must interact with the service in the background.
Having read this article [Microsoft .NET Compact Framework Background Processing Techniques](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446488.aspx). I decided to use the Asynchronous Web Service Call. There http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa347733.aspx I found the /async parameter, but it appeared to not work for the NetCFSvcUtil.exe.

What can I do to get the async proxy for my smart device application? Is there a way to generate it or I'm expected to add async methods to the interface with my own hands? Maybe it would be suitable for .Net CF to use SvcUtil.exe to generate the async proxy in my case?

Comment: Discovered for myself an opportunity to use a web reference from a web site, representing the wcf service. Haven't tested yet...but will it limit me to hosting the service on IIS (or smth)? The original idea was to host it in a windows service. The target system is not going to have IIS, and is not expected to be complicated by administrating it.

Comment: What version device are you using and what development tool (Visual Studio?) and version is it?

Comment: We use Visual Studio 2008 (as there is no support for smart device projects in VS 2010). I do not know the exact device, but its OS is going to be Windows Mobile 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it worked. The "Add web reference" tool created a proxy with Begin/End async methods and the proxy interacted with the wcf service hosted by a simple console application (later a windows service) through the URL property of the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

A further more information like which platform you are using to build your Smart phone application would be helpful.

I have done Blackberry development and consumed web services. There are two ways you could build your web services

1. RestFul Service - Consumption of web services would be pretty easy. Posting data could be a little pain as multipart form data is posted as stream in Wcf - Rest Starter Kit
2. Soap Service - If you decide to use SOAP, then for blackberry and Android you have to use preverified KSOAP -2 to send and receive soap messages between your app and the web service. If you decide to use KSOAP -2 , go back ASMX services. Somehow WCF services does not communicate with KSOAP -2 (due to change in SOAP version or something) where as a simple ASMX service works pretty smoothly. There are dozens of article which you could use to learn how to use KSOAP

> he original idea was to host it in a windows service...

Windows Services could never be web facing. If you want any thing to be web facing, you need a Web Server !

Comment: The target platform for the client is Windows Mobile. The application type is -  windows forms..the service is going to be consumed by the client in question. The problem is that I wanted to have the async operations of the service to be generated.

Comment: Take a look at this. Looks promising  http://www.redigokaj.com/windows-mobile-7-application-using-asp-net-webservice.blog

Comment: The Web is not the aim, it appeares to be the mean to get those async operations generated only. But it may lead to some other limitations, may it? I mean, could I use, say, IIS only to add a web reference to my smart device project and then deploy the service somewhere else (console application, windows service, etc.)? Will the client be able to communicate with it then?

Comment: Oops, from where I am now, unfortunately cannot watch video, some time later only..

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong in understanding of your problem. There are some tasks, which you want to do in background. You want this task to deletegated to some service as you do not want to overload your phone.
May I ask something? What is this processing task which you want to do.there are ways of doing thing in background thread in Windows Mobile directly so that UI does not gloats. Also if you want service, then it has to on web, other wise people who are loacted remotely would not be able to communicate with it

Comment: The Wcf service must be located in that center and service the devices  over wi-fi

Comment: We already have it working, the wcf service is temporarily hosted by a simple console application. But the client is not async.

Comment: http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/11/29/an-introduction-to-wcf-for-device-developers.aspx

Comment: Ah, I get it. So every body could log in to his account and get all the tasks that are assigned to him. Since, all your device would be using wcf, and would be probably in same network, you do not need to make it web facing then. One thing still which is not clear to me, what you want to do async here. Because i think, this is the case of simple hitting the service, the service will then hit database retrieves all the data related to your user and display it. The data could be very large so that service could take very large amount of time.

Comment: The best way to do it, is make another thread to call the service. You should never call web service on UI thread never, other wise it would hang your device

Comment: We have some kind of center where all data is accumulated. An operator creates tasks for devices there. Devices connect to the center, get the new tasks and send the information about the progress. So as soon as they have their tasks on board, the users of the devices can start doing it. In the center the operator can see the progress in "real time" as far as devices send info periodically

Comment: Actually I hoped that Asynchronous XML Web Services (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446488.aspx) is what I need as far as I'm having a wcf service and have no need to develop it explicitly. Or is it better to use thread pooling? Or what is the best practice to  do work in background under .Net CF?

Comment: Found some thoughts on what I am asking, but not what I really need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550922/wcf-proxy-generation-on-windows-mobile-application?rq=1

Comment: Probably some more suitable info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2007/09/13/calling-wcf-services-from-netcf-3-5-using-compact-wcf-and-netcfsvcutil-exe.aspx